# How to deploy cakephp application on ubuntu server

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, ubuntu

I’m developing a Cakephp medium size application since four month. Previous it was deployed on windows server where it was working perfect. 
Now it is required to deploy on Ubuntu server. I made a folder project on root and I’ve checkout code according to following

```
/project
    /app
    /build
    /vendor
    /plugin
```

This is my configuration detail

Ubuntu 13.10

PHP Version 5.5.3

Msql API version 5.5.34

This is mu apache configuration **etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

        ServerAdmin system@webmaster.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost >
```

Apache mode_rewrite is on and read write access is given to entire project folder .It seems like it is apache issue.

It is displaying project directory when I hit the server and when i click on project, it gives me errors/warningFatal

**Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /var/www/project/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 310**

**Warning: /var/www/project/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/project/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 337**

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /var/www/project/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:166 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/project/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(136): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_') #1 /var/www/project/app/Config/core.php(336): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array) #2 /var/www/project/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(78): include('/var/www/projec...') #3 /var/www/project/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(171): Configure::bootstrap(true) #4 /var/www/project/app/webroot/index.php(96): include('/var/www/projec...') #5 /var/www/project/index.php(43): require('/var/www/projec...') #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/project/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 166**

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem you are seeing?

Your /project directory  should be put in /var/www and then the DocumentRoot changed to /var/www/project in the VirtualHost.  Remember to reload or restart Apache after changing the VirtualHost.

Comment: I've updated my question. do you mean DocumentRoot should be /var/www/project ? because project directory start from project folder

Comment: I've change DocumentRoot as you said, now it is displaying same error on root

Comment: I see.  You need to create the directory at  /var/www/project/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ and set the permissions to b writeable by the webserver.

chmod -R 0775  /var/www/project/app/tmp/cache/persistent/

should solve it.

Comment: and made the missing folders and modify documentRoot with  /var/www/project/app/webroot. it is display correct home page, but on click on different controller it is showing blank page of apache

Comment: First, check Apache's error log to see what errors are being reported.  'tail -n 20 /var/log/apache2/error.log' (or similar) will show the last 20 lines of the error log.

Have you enabled Apache's rewrite module? This isn't available by default in Ubuntu.  As root, run 'a2enmod rewrite' and then restart Apache.

Comment: Yes was enable. BTW i've fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

by "folder project on root" do you mean you put it inside /root (~)? Because your DocumentRoot is still set to /var/www.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: If u are on Linux, switch off SELinux. It is a nightmare!

```
setenforce 0
```